# Custom column in SQL with specific filters on each row

Tags: sql

I am trying to add an extra column to my table in SQL that is dependant on values from another table. Usually this would be simple but each row has its own "if" clause that changes row by row. Is there a way to code this in SQL? The example tables look like what ive illustrated below, with the column "REQUIRED FIELD" being what im trying to add to Table1, using information from table2. The issue is the table2 is independent from table1 with regards to the KEY and VALUE columns

```
            TABLE1                                   TABLE2
| Key1     | Value_1  | REQUIRED FIELD |         | Key2     | Value_2  |
| -------- | -------- | -------------- |         | -------- | -------- |
| A        | 4        | x              |         | D        | 39       |
| B        | 10       | y              |         | E        | 42       |
```

In this example, the REQUIRED FIELD value "x" would be the logic of "sum the Value_2 for when key2 is equal to D or E" and the value "y" would be the logic "sum the Value_2 for when key2 is equal to D". So x=81 and y=39.

Comment: Don't store calculated values like that, you will soon have inconsistent data. Create a view instead, or at least use triggers.